# Помогите связать несколько таксономий

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Как можно связать несколько таксономий, чтобы url получился таким :

site.ru/products/phone/samsung/s-10

Есть произвольный тип записи «Продукты»

- В нем есть 2 таксономии:

  1. Типы
  2. Бренды

» Должен открывать все продукты
site.ru/products/phone

» Должен показать все посты данной таксономии «Телефоны»
site.ru/products/phone/samsung

» Должен показать все посты данной таксономии «Телефоны» и бренда «Samsung»
site.ru/products/phone/samsung/s-10

» Должен открыть пост с названием s-10

### Помогите разобраться в этом

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет в этом https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule но задача не простая) Что-то вроде этого:

```
add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');
function do_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '^(products)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&type=$matches[2]&brand=$matches[3]', 'top' ); 
}
```